# Looking to add a "itemprop" tag into a div using JS or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to insert the itemprop span into the below offer. It needs to be done using JS or JQuery as I can't actually edit the below code directly.

```
<span itemprop="currency" content="CAD" />
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! (A CSS solution would also work)

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr><td>
<div class="product_productprice">
<span class="PageText_L335n">Price (CAD)</span>: <span itemprop="price">$119.00</span>
</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
<meta itemprop="availability" content="InStock">
</div>
```

Comment: more explain about question and what you desire

Comment: Does Google read JavaScript generated markup?

Comment: That's a good question Salman A. I was assuming it would, but I suppose it would depend what order Google 'reads' the page in. Whether it fully loads first or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var a=$('span').attr('itemprop');//get value of itemprop of span==>'currency'
$("div[itemprop='offers']").attr('itemprop',a);//add 'currency' to div with itemprop='offers'
```

by `prop` or `attr` can get,set attribute of elements.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context about why this answers the question, and what the code does? That'll help this person and future ones as well...

Comment: What does `.prop` do?

Comment: prop get value of attribute of elements